# Query from a function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have this query

```
Select distinct a.name,
p1.ref as book,
p2.ref as text,
p3.ref as note
from library a
left join room p1 on a.id=p1.id 
left join room p2 on a.id=p2.id 
left join room p3 on a.id=p3.id
```

I started creating the function as below. The output of the function needs to be the above query. The p1, p2 and p3 are dynamically generated

```
rlsql varchar2(12000) := 'select distinct ';
rlsql := rlsql||'ref as '||c_var.name||',';
rlsql := rlsql||chr(13)||chr(10);
rlsql := rlsql||' from library';

rlsql := rlsql||' left join room on a.id='||c_var.id||'
```

when I execute the above part of function then it returning me as the below sample

```
Select distinct 
ref as book from library,
ref as text from library,
ref as note from library
```

How to remove the "from library" on each line and how to get p1. ,p2. ,p3. dynamically

Any help on this is highly appreciated

Comment: you may perform this by taking column parts in a loop, and taking part `from library` out of loop. Please elaborate your question by sharing complete pl/sql code with us.

Comment: Post the complete function along with he inputs, the actual output and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** this line where you concatenate `' from library'`

```
rlsql := rlsql||' from library';
```